# ASP.NET MVC Form Validation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

>" %>

Index

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    input[type=text]
    input[type=checkbox]
</script>

<h2>
    Todays Cases</h2>
<div>
    <%= Html.Encode(ViewData["message"]) %>
</div>
<form action="/TodaysCases/Index" method="post" id="rxForm">
<table>

    <% foreach (var item in Model)
       { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.LastName+", "+item.FirstName) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.Age) %>
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="NoComments" id="<%= item.CaseNumber%>" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Comments" id="comment_<%= item.CaseNumber%>" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>
                Yes
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="CaseNumber" type="hidden" value="<%=item.CaseNumber %>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Sign" />
</form>
```

In my model depending on how many cases are scheduled for today I may have one and upto 15 cases. So the page when displayed will have upto 15 rows. Each row will have a check box and a comment field. What I want to achieve with Java Script is the client side validation. Of course I will do the server side validation as well.  If the box is checked, then it means no comments, so I want to clear the corresponding comment field. if the box is unchecked, I want to force the user to have put some comment before submission of the form. Basically if there is some comment the user puts some comments. If no comments he check the box, ie, take some action. How do I go about doing this in Javascript? I learnt jQuery thinking I could do it there but I could not figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Beta, you can take advantage of the built-in, client-side validation that it provides.

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx